# How often are label recordings off-note: sped up or slowed down?

Tags: recording

How rare is it that recordings are sped up or slowed down after recording, by a few percent, during the mastering process?

Answer (score 3):

Not that rare.  The producer felt a little extra energy could be gained by raising the speed and/or pitch a little. Or there may be more pragmatic reasons, making changes to fit in with the pitch or speed of what precedes or follows.

Comment: You mean that tracks are often changed to match the tempo of another song in a DJ mix? I meant individual song recordings. ... The producer can choose to change the speed of the recording that the artists played at, there is not taboo agains that, I should definately foresee that, when programming chord recognition program , the keyof A can be arbitrary adn not 440khz? I am wondering what kind of error level i would get ina chord recognition program if i presume that all recordings are in universal digital tuning standard of A=440.

Comment: That wasn't what I meant, but it could also happen.

Answer (score 3):

This used to be common before the days of digital - often the record company would complain to the producer that a song is too fast or too slow and the option would be to vary the tape speed on the master.

Comment: John Lennon often had his recordings slowed down a bit to lower the pitch of his voice --he felt he sang too high.  And KC (of the Sunshine Gang) used sped up instrumentals as a signature part of his sound.

Comment: Why only before the days of digital?  Faster doesn't HAVE to mean higher now, but there's a lot of nostalgia for the "old ways" in the recording world!

Comment: Even with the current pitch shifting algorithms, it's not so easy to pitch shift in the digital domain without loosing quality and adding artefacts - particularly if the track has a lot of acoustic guitars, cymbals or vocals.